# SQL Server: Stored Procedure trying to insert NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> ```
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure CreateParty, Line 16
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'DEVIN.dbo.Party';
> ```
>
> column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.
>       The statement has been terminated.
>
> ```
> (1 row(s) affected)
> ```

What the hell? My table consists of

```
Id (Primary Key)
FirstName
LastName
```

Here's my stored procedure:

```
USE [DEVIN]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CreateParty]    Script Date: 11/19/2010 16:59:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateParty]
    @firstname varchar(50),
    @lastname varchar(50)
    --@emailaddress varchar(100),
    --@zipcode char(5)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Party (FirstName, LastName)
    Values (@firstname,@lastname)

END
```

Can someone find out why the heck I would be getting that error? It's so annoying...

---

Also, for some reason, SQL Management is only showing the "Id" column in intellisense. I have no idea why...

SCREENSHOT:
[image]

Does it not already have the identity "PK_Party"? It does this automatically.. I must be missing something...

Comment: Is Id an IDENTITY column? PK alone does not insert values

Comment: Are you sure that the `Id` column is an `Identity`? The error seems to indicate that it might not be. That might be why it is indicating that you need to explicitly insert that value in your `insert`statement alongwith the rest of the columns

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement for the `PARTY` table.

Comment: Have you **refreshed** your Intellisense cache?? Press Ctrl-Shift-R to refresh ....

Comment: How exactly to I give the "id" column an identity?

Comment: It does not makea column an idntity automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is ID an identity as well as a primary key?  A PK by itself doesn't fill in any data for the column on insert.

Answer (score 8):

```
INSERT INTO Party (FirstName, LastName)
    Values (@firstname,@lastname)
```

You do no specify a value for the column `Id`, therefore the INSERT will attempt to insert the *default* value:

- for an `IDENTITY()` column, the default value will be the next identity
- for a column with a `DEFAULT` constraint, the default value will be the value of the constraint
- everything else will be `NULL`

Post the *Exact* definition of your table so we can tell you what is your column default value.

Answer (score 0):

Drop and recreate your table with the identity specified. If you have data in it already, it is more complicated than that.

Example of scritp to  create a table with an identity:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE MyTable
GO


CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LASTNAME] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [FIRSTNAME] [varchar](500) NULL


) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create primary key value identical I.e. auto increment.
As primary key is heaving cluster index and it cannot be null.
You have to create identity increment by 1 or any value.

As for now you have to create table again and through design you have to increment value.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use code

```
INSERT INTO Party
Values (@firstname,@lastname)
```

instead of `INSERT INTO Party (FirstName, LastName)
    Values (@firstname,@lastname)`

Comment: I thought it was that simple, but apparently when creating a table in SQL, it's not as simple as setting a primary key...